# Div height and width not being set in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set the width and height of a div in javascript but it is not being set. I have tried a lot but nothing is working. Here is what i have tried,

```html
<div id="d1">asdasd</div>

<script>
  var d = document.getElementById("d1");
  d.style.width = "100px";
  d.style.height = "100px";
  d.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black;'
</script>
```

Please check what is the problem!

Comment: CAnt you fix directly in css?

Comment: No I have to do this in javascript. As i have to use values from js variables!

Comment: Have a look at [this demo](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13227316/1269037) - it does what you need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think `d.style.cssText` overwrites `width` and `height` properties

Try this:

```
var d = document.getElementById("d1");
d.style.width = "100px";
d.style.height = "100px";
d.style.cssText += 'border:1px solid black;'
```

Comment: Even if i don't write that line it doesn't set the height and width!

Answer (score 3):

As karaxuna mentioned, your `d.style.cssText` is overwriting the width and height settings. Simply changing your code to either this:

```
var d = document.getElementById("d1");
d.style.width = "100px";
d.style.height = "100px";
d.style.border = '1px solid black';
```

or this:

```
var d = document.getElementById("d1");
d.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black;'
d.style.width = "100px";
d.style.height = "100px";
```

works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is with `d.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black;'` . it is overriding the width and height set by JS .

Check this fiddle:-

http://jsfiddle.net/RZKnQ/1/

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
<div id="d1" style="border:1px solid black;">asdasd</div>​
<script>
var d = document.getElementById("d1");
d.style.height = "200px";
</script>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/dandv/emnMb/4/

Answer (score 1):

An alternate would be to define a new style element in CSS and simply set `d.className` to that CSS element.

I guess

```
d.style.cssText
```

is problem

Answer (score 0):

Change sequence of your JS statements it will work i.e.

```
<script>
    var d = document.getElementById("d1");
    d.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black;'
    d.style.width = "100px";
    d.style.height = "100px";
</script>
```

**Better** put width, height properties in style attribute only. i.e.

d.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black; width:100px; height:100px'

**or in CSS class**

Answer (score 0):

```
d.style.cssText = 'border:1px solid black;'
d.style.float="left";
d.style.width = "100px";
d.style.height = "100px";​
```

You neeed to use float:left attribute.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what your problem is but I've used this and this worked

```
    function fnc1()
{
    document.getElementById("d1").style.width="100px";
    document.getElementById("d1").style.height="100px";
    document.getElementById("d1").style.backgroundColor="red";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="d1">asdasd</div>​
```

Javascript

```
document.getElementById('d1').style.height = 90+'px';​
```

[working demo here](http://jsfiddle.net/eEeLz/) ( works fine with chrome, din't check with other browsers )